# how to display tab in right side using html CSS bootstrap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

what i am trying to do is in my below code when i click on checkbox2 then tab panes red green and blue is show in right side above the add new button and when i unclick then add new button is coming in original position.

i try to make this type functionality https://kapwi.ng/w/3zPHfzol any help in this

in below my code i tried using if else condition but its not work

can anyone help me out this functionality.

i try to make when i click on first checkbox1 then variant and add new tab is show and when i lick on check box 2 then red green blue tab pan is show in above the add new tab and when i uncheck the checkbox2 then add new tab is coming ur own position. this type  functionality i want to create.

my expected functionality look like this https://kapwi.ng/w/3zPHfzol

its vey thankful

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("mardi");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    mardi.style.display = "block";
     xyz.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
     mardi.style.display = "none";
      xyz.style.display = "none";
     
  }
}

function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container-2{
display:flex}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

<div class="container">
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" />2
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>


<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">
  
    <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#homemade">variant</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="homemade" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD NEW</button>
      
    </div>
      </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
      <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" >
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Colors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  

</div>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="xyz"  style="display:none;">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"  id="abc">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Blue</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">test</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing in the link - https://kapwi.ng/w/3zPHfzol.. Please add the image and post the proper link. Thanks

Comment: https://ibb.co/kKtrNk8 this one plz check

Answer (score 0):

why can't u add a add new button tab div to variant button list(make another li tag in same ul variant button tag) hope this helps u!

Comment: i try but not work actually can u show me something its very help for me

Comment: in my below code i tried this document.getElementById("xyz").style.left = "200px"; to  red green blue tab show above the add new tab but not work actually

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("mardi");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    mardi.style.display = "block";
    xyz.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("xyz").style.left = "200px";
    
  } else {
     mardi.style.display = "none";
      xyz.style.display = "none";
     
  }
}
function addDay(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.value).style.display = e.checked ? "initial" : "none";
}
```

```css
.container-2{
display:flex}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="lundi" id="lundiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />1
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mardi" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" />2
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="mercredi" id="mercrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />3
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="jeudi" id="jeudiCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />4
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="vendredi" id="vendrediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />5
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="samedi" id="samediCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />6
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" value="dimanche" id="dimancheCheck" onclick="addDay(this)" />7
</div>


<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="lundi">
  
    <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#homemade">variant</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="homemade" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD NEW</button>
      
    </div>
      </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mardi">
      <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" >
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Colors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  

</div>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="xyz"  style="display:none;">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"  id="abc">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Blue</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="mercredi">test</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="jeudi">Some content4</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="vendredi">Some content5</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="samedi">Some content6</div>
  <div class="row mr-2 ml-0" style="display:none;" id="dimanche">Some content6</div>
</div>
```